# How to base a Perforce changelist on another pending changelist

Tags: version-control, perforce

Suppose I have finished some code for job A, but can't `p4 submit` until the code has been reviewed. Now I have to move on to job B, which depends on the changes I made in job A.

How would one ensure that the changes for job A are saved so that they can be submitted separately later (maybe after some further changes), **and** save the job B modifications (diff A..B) *only* onto a new changelist (which needs to be to shelveable at some point so that it can also be reviewed)?

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use case for branching.  The rub with trying to do everything with shelves is that shelved revisions are impermanent, so you can't have history that's based off them.  If you create a branch, you can isolate your changes from the files that everyone else is working on, but still have them saved somewhere permanent.

The golden rule is "branch on incompatible submit policy".  In this case you need to make a submit of unreviewed work (so you can do more work on top of it) but the branch you're in doesn't permit unreviewed work -- so make a new branch that does!

I'll assume for this example that you're using streams because it makes everything quicker; the same exact workflow happens with unmanaged branches, it's just more commands to type.

So let's assume you're currently in stream "main" and you have unsubmitted changes.  Bring your changes into a new branch (I'll call it "dev-bob" on the assumption your name is Bob) like this:

```
p4 switch -r -c dev-bob
```

Now submit:

```
p4 submit
```

Now go ahead and make your other changes.

To get your changes into "main" and shelve them for review do:

```
p4 switch main
p4 merge --from dev-bob
p4 resolve -am
p4 shelve
```

To get everything up to a particular change "A" from dev-bob you'd add "@A" to the merge command.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is not possible in perforce.

One workaround is to have two copies of your work-space. When you are done with job A, *shelve* the changelist in first work-space. Keep this copy of code until your code-review is done.

Now, move to second work-space, *unshelve* the saved changelist for job A, and make whatever changes you want to make on top of it for job B.

Once job A is submitted to the server, do *p4 sync* on second work-space and *p4 diff* will show changes done on top of job A.

Comment: You don't really need a second workspace for this. Once you've shelved the files, they are safe on the server. I think you could remove your first sentence because this technique addresses all the original questioner's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Perforce's support for 'clone, fetch, push'?

Both your server and client must be at least at 2015.1, but once they are, you can make cloned copies of the code on your workstation, submit various changes to the code, make branches, push either branches or shelves to your review server for review, etc.

In addition to copying changes between your clones and the central server, you can also copy changes from one of your DVCS instances to another one, thus enabling many of the DVCS workflows that many developers find convenient.

Answer (score -1):

If I can just throw in my opinion here.

There should never be a situation that prevents you from submitting code.  As a developer you should be able to submit whatever code you want to whenever you want to.  Code should be reviewed after being submitted not before.  The whole point of source control is that it controls sourcecode, once the code is in you can roll it back, modify it, delete it, but you have a record.

If you are forced to jump through hoops to do something as basic as what you are describing then the workflow in your company is mangled or the admins do not understand how to use perforce in any but the most trivial manner.

There are very simple ways of keeping your code seperate until it has been reviewed (branches being the simplest), keeping it out of source control is not one of them.

Imagine how github.com would cease to function if you couldnt checkin code until it had been reviewed.

Comment: I'm confused; what answer are you offering here? Note that several approaches have already been suggested in other answers; there's no indication that anything is "prevents you from submitting code."

Comment: Sure. That's why the other answers suggested shelves, branches, review servers, multiple workspaces, DVCS workflows, etc. Lots of ways to collaborate prior to your final commit to the master branch.

Comment: Or, perhaps, your answer is: "educate management that they should not have such restrictive policies." In which case, I'm sorry I didn't understand that at first; that certainly would resolve the original question.